What is Abel's "algebraic function" in his proof of insolvability of quintic?
I'm trying to understand Abel's pre-Galois proof of insolvability of the quintic, summarized by Jim Brown [1]. The proof starts with a notion of "algebraic functions":

To Abel, an equation is solvable by radicals if the roots are what Abel calls algebraic functions. Recall that a rational function is the ratio of two polynomials. Abel defines an algebraic function of the 0-th order to be a rational function of the coefficients. For example, $f_0(a,b,c) = \frac{a^5 - 4bc}{b^5 - 2c}$ would be an algebraic function of the 0-th order. An algebraic function of the 1-st order is a function $f_1(f_0^\frac{1}{m})$ where $f_0$ is an algebraic function of the 0-th ordre and $f_1$ is a rational function of the coefficients and $f_0^\frac{1}{m}$ to the 0-th order. An example of an algebraic function of the 1-st order would be $f_1(a,b,c) = \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$ where for this example we have $f_0 = b^2 - 4ac$ and $m=2$. Similarly, we can define an algebraic function of any positivie order $k$ to be a function $f_k(f_{k-1}^\frac{1}{m_k})$ where $f_{k-1}$ is an algebraic function of order $k-1$, $m_k$ is a positive integer, and $f_k$ is a rational function of the coefficients and $f_{k-1}^\frac{1}{m_k}$. We call an algebraic function of some positive order $k$ an algebraic function.

This definition is used in a key theorem:

(Theorem 6.1) Any algebraic function $y$ solving equation $y^5 - ay^4 + by^3 - cy^2 + dy - e = 0$ can be written in the form
$$y = a_0 + a_1 R^\frac{1}{p} + a_2 R^\frac{2}{p} + \dots + a_{p-1} R^\frac{p-1}{p}$$
with $p$ a prime and $a_0, \dots, a_{p-1}, R$ are algebraic functions of lower order than $y$.

and the proof of the theorem starts with:

Let $v$ be an algebraic function as in the statement of the theorem. By definition, we can write $v = \frac{F}{G}$ where
$$G = g_0 + g_1 R^\frac{1}{p} + g_2 R^\frac{2}{p} + \dots + g_q R^\frac{q}{p}$$
for some $q \in \mathbf{N}$ and $p$ prime and similarly for $F$.

I'm confused between two possible interpretations of this so-called "algebraic function", each of which has its own problem.
First interpretation: "algebraic function" describes precisely a syntax tree of expressions consisting of $+,-,\times,/$, roots, coefficients, and natural numbers.
Problem 1: it is not clear why "by definition, we can write $v=\frac{F}{G}$ where $G = g_0 + g_1 R^\frac{1}{p} + g_2 R^\frac{2}{p} + \dots + g_q R^\frac{q}{p}$", which is only a special form of the syntax tree.
Problem 2: the theorem is trivially true, because the following stronger theorem holds: "any algebraic function $y$ solving equation $y^5 - ay^4 + by^3 - cy^2 + dy - e = 0$ can be written in the form $y = a_0$ where $a_0$ (despite being identical to $y$) is an algebraic function of lower order than $y$. This is because $y=a_0$ can be written as $y=f(a_0^\frac{1}{m})$ with $m=1$ and $f$ being the identity function and thus rational, which makes $y$ higher order than $a_0$. Such stronger theorem, however, means nothing but "$y$ can be renamed to $a_0$".
Second interpretation: "algebraic function" is a subset of the syntax trees, with some kind of properties.
Problem 1: the definition is incomplete, because $f_k(f_{k-1}^\frac{1}{m_k})$ talks about only chains of roots, excluding trees. For example, $\sqrt{a+\sqrt[3]{b}}$ is an algebraic function, but $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt[3]{b}$ is not, since its neither a rational function of $\sqrt{a}$ nor of $\sqrt[3]{b}$.
Problem 2: even if problem 1 is solved, as long as "algebraic function" is only a restricted subset of syntax tree, it is still not clearly why such upfront restriction is justified.
In summary, I would like to ask what Abel wants to characterized with his "algebraic function"?
[1] https://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/abel_proof.pdf

It doesn't make sense to call roots any kind of function., since roots are complex numbers, and functiof the polynomial parametersons are functions. Do you mean "can be <expressed by algebraic functions," maybe?

Abel's notion of Algebraic functions matches exactly with the notion of radical extensions in modern language of Galois theory. Abel really had deep insight here about expressing solvability by radicals in concrete terms. I have discussed some parts of Abel's proof with modern notation in my blog posts. You may start with this post https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/12/abel-and-the-insolvability-of-the-quintic-part-1.html?m=0 and follow next three posts.
